# Creating ObjectNodes using Jackson ObjectWriter

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to increase the reuse of ObjectMapper and I am currently considering moving the following code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule().addSerializer(WeirdStuff.class, new WeirdStuffToStringSerializer());

mapper.registerModule(module);
ObjectNode results = mapper.createObjectNode();


results.set("field1", mapper.valueToTree(myClass.getField1()));
results.set("field2", mapper.valueToTree(myClass.getField2()));
```

to a shared `ObjectMapper` and an `ObjectWriter`, however, examples using ObjectReader and Writer are hard to find. Looking at the JavaDocs I also could not find ObjectWriter's equivalent to `valueToTree`.

Is there a way of creating `ObjectNodes` out of ObjectWriter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the conversion methods (ex. `valueToTree`, `convertValue`, etc.) that you find on `ObjectMapper` are not present in `ObjectWriter` or `ObjectReader` because they need both serialization and deserialization functionality.

To answer your question of creating `ObjectNode`s from an `ObjectWriter`, the answer is no. `ObjectWriter` is for serializing and creating `JsonNode`s is for deserializing. With `ObjectReader`, you could create them by getting the `NodeFactory`:

```
objectReader.getConfig().getNodeFactory().objectNode()
```